# What is the .id in the code means? is it the rowid pseudocolumn?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to oracle and I am experimenting with various codes.I was practising sql in oracle live sql worksheet and quick sql  Shorthand. QUICK SQL shorthand gave a ready-made code on departments and employees where i dont understand 
this line **where
    employees.department_id = departments.id**. I dont understand **.id column** as there is no .id column created during table creation of departments. Is it the department_id column(pkey) which is automatically generated via foreign key reference in the Employees table?or is it pseudocolumn.

I have come across rowid pseudocolumn in oracle sql documentation.

**This is the CODE**

```
create table departments (
    name                           varchar2(255) not null,
    location                       varchar2(4000),
    country                        varchar2(4000)
)
;

create table employees (
    department_id                  number
                                   constraint employees_department_id_fk
                                   references departments on delete cascade,
    name                           varchar2(50) not null,
    email                          varchar2(255),
    cost_center                    number,
    date_hired                     date,
    job                            varchar2(255)
)
;


-- triggers
create or replace trigger departments_biu
    before insert or update 
    on departments
    for each row
begin
    null;
end departments_biu;
/

create or replace trigger employees_biu
    before insert or update 
    on employees
    for each row
begin
    :new.email := lower(:new.email);
end employees_biu;
/


-- indexes
create index employees_i1 on employees (department_id);

-- create views
create or replace view emp_v as 
select 
    departments.name                                   department_name,
    departments.location                               location,
    departments.country                                country,
    employees.name                                     employee_name,
    employees.email                                    email,
    employees.cost_center                              cost_center,
    employees.date_hired                               date_hired,
    employees.job                                      job
from 
    departments,
    employees
where
    *employees.department_id(+) = departments.id;*
/

-- load data

insert into departments (
    name,
    location,
    country
) values (
    'Government Sales',
    'Tanquecitos',
    'United States'
);

insert into departments (
    name,
    location,
    country
) values (
    'Security',
    'Sugarloaf',
    'United States'
);

insert into departments (
    name,
    location,
    country
) values (
    'Finance',
    'Dale City',
    'United States'
);

insert into departments (
    name,
    location,
    country
) values (
    'Customer Support',
    'Grosvenor',
    'United States'
);

commit;
-- load data

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Gricelda Luebbers',
    'gricelda.luebbers@aaab.com',
    76,
    sysdate - 63,
    'Engineer'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Dean Bollich',
    'dean.bollich@aaac.com',
    35,
    sysdate - 93,
    'Security Specialist'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Milo Manoni',
    'milo.manoni@aaad.com',
    100,
    sysdate - 90,
    'Marketing Manager'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Laurice Karl',
    'laurice.karl@aaae.com',
    43,
    sysdate - 16,
    'Accounting Analyst'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'August Rupel',
    'august.rupel@aaaf.com',
    66,
    sysdate - 44,
    'President'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Salome Guisti',
    'salome.guisti@aaag.com',
    11,
    sysdate - 70,
    'Sales Representative'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Lovie Ritacco',
    'lovie.ritacco@aaah.com',
    7,
    sysdate - 18,
    'Sales Representative'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Chaya Greczkowski',
    'chaya.greczkowski@aaai.com',
    21,
    sysdate - 33,
    'Data Architect'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Twila Coolbeth',
    'twila.coolbeth@aaaj.com',
    9,
    sysdate - 95,
    'Webmaster'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Carlotta Achenbach',
    'carlotta.achenbach@aaak.com',
    51,
    sysdate - 82,
    'Security Specialist'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Jeraldine Audet',
    'jeraldine.audet@aaal.com',
    54,
    sysdate - 12,
    'Help Desk Specialist'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'August Arouri',
    'august.arouri@aaam.com',
    32,
    sysdate - 26,
    'Marketing Manager'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Ward Stepney',
    'ward.stepney@aaan.com',
    8,
    sysdate - 62,
    'Business Applications'
);

insert into employees (
    department_id,
    name,
    email,
    cost_center,
    date_hired,
    job
) values (
    1,
    'Ayana Barkhurst',
    'ayana.barkhurst@aaao.com',
    25,
    sysdate - 93,
    'Webmaster'
);

commit;
```

**WHAT IS THE .id column in the code?**

Comment: Is there a link to this "Quick SQL Shorthand"? It seems they missed out a column in the `departments` table. There is no implicit or built-in `ID` pseudocolumn in Oracle, although if it was defined as an [identity column](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/migr_tools_feat.htm#DRDAA109) you would not reference it in `insert` statements.

Comment: [quicksql](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:800:105168614538870::LEVEL1:::)  here is the code that i have pasted here

Comment: Thanks. It seems you have copied the generated code which is shown in the preview pane, but this is not valid. You need to use the 'Copy to Worksheet' button which generates valid DDL.

Comment: [sqlworksheet](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/f?p=590:1:134325974843064::NO:::)  the code was copied but still the same. I want to know another thing why the output is not giving any table view.

Comment: What is "table view"? If you mean why don't you see any query results, it's because you either didn't run the commands in the worksheet, or you tried and it failed due to the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the definition of the DEPARTMENTS table is missing a field named `ID`, which should be of data type `NUMBER`, and furthermore should be the primary key on the DEPARTMENTS table. I'm basing this on the fact that in the EMPLOYEES table there is a `DEPARTMENT_ID` field, of type NUMBER, which is a foreign key referencing the DEPARTMENTS table. As shown above there is no PRIMARY KEY on DEPARTMENTS, so the (missing) `ID` column should be the primary key.

I suggest that the DEPARTMENTS table should be defined as:

```
create table departments (
    ID                             NUMBER
      CONSTRAINT PK_DEPARTMENTS
        PRIMARY KEY
          USING INDEX,
    name                           varchar2(255) not null,
    location                       varchar2(4000),
    country                        varchar2(4000)
);
```

Furthermore, the trigger DEPARTMENTS_BIU should be defined as follows:

```
create or replace trigger departments_biu
    before insert or update 
    on departments
    for each row
begin
    IF :NEW.ID IS NULL THEN
      :NEW.ID := DEPARTMENTS_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
    END IF;
end departments_biu;
```

which means you need to define DEPARTMENTS_SEQ:

```
CREATE DEPARTMENTS_SEQ
  MINVALUE 1
  NOMAXVALUE
  START WITH 1
  NOCACHE;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: i am not bothered about the trigger part for now . I asked the question keeping one thing mind that what is this **.id column** that they directly used without defining it. The code that quck sql shorthand provided was that only.They did not defined but **it is working fine**. SO this means that we dont have to define .id column in the CREATE PART  to use it in oracle ?